# Compose one JPA Entity from multiple databases

Tags: java, spring, jpa, microservices, domain-driven-design

I am currently developing a new system that is based on a legacy application. The legacy application has its own database holding entities and cannot be changed in any way.

Due to a new requirement, I need to add new attributes to the entities from the legacy application. I was wondering how I would go about designing the object model of my new application? I am using JPA to store entities in a separate database.

My first instinct is to only store the added attributes with a reference to the id provided by the legacy application. If someone requests the entity I would request the base data from the legacy application and fetch the additional attributes from my database. I then create a new object which holds all the required fields and return it.
This would require me to add a class like "AdditionalAttributes", mark it as a JPA Entity, and implement a JPA Repository. Is this the way to go or is there a more elegant way? I feel like I am forced to create this "AdditionalAttributes" class which feels wrong to me and does not really reflect the domain well.

I hope someone can help me out

Thank you

Comment: Will these attributes still continue to be changed in the legacy database by the legacy application? Or will the legacy application (which cannot be changed if I understand you right) just keep reading the data from the legacy database?

Answer (score 0):

You should create two microservices:

1. Which will contain new attributes(because can't modify legacy service) and manage them.
2. Which will consume 2 services the legacy application and the new created service. You got the mapping here and have a model(which have attributes of the both services).

Comment: Thank you, I can see how this solves my problem but isn't it a bit excessive to create a completely new microservice just to add two attributes. It is probably nice to have this kind of separation in the future when other services need the additional attributes too. Right now I would refrain from this solution because I only need the additional attributes in one place (and this won't change in the near future)